# Binding without router link to show id's Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a problem when it comes to displaying an edit button for each battery, I want to redirect each icon to its corresponding path, but I have only managed to print the 4 id's at the same time for each battery, I show some screenshots so that it is understood best:

routes.ts

```
    { path: 'edit-capacitor-bank/:id', component: EditCapacitorBankComponent },
```

dashboard.html:

```
<div class="c-dashboard">
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="data">
                <div class="card card-cascade narrower border-top-0" *ngFor="let cb of serialNumber; index as i;">
                    <div class="b-data">
                        <img class="center-block" src="{{image[i]}}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <li class="menu-edit-CB">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye mr-3 text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a *ngFor="let aid of aID" [routerLink]="['/edit-capacitor-bank', aid.id]"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o mr-3 text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash mr-3 text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div>
                            <p class="text-center"><strong>Alias: </strong>{{alias[i]}}</p>
                            <p class="text-center"><strong>Serial Number: </strong> {{ serialNumber[i] }}</p>
                            <p class="text-center"><strong>Company: </strong>{{company[i]}}</p>
                            <p class="text-center"><strong>Monthly Cos: </strong>{{monthlyCos[i]}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

dashboard.ts:

```
export class CapacitorBankFileComponent implements OnInit {
     assetID = {};
      aID = [];
 ngOnInit() {
      // Server Attributes Assets
          this.cbank.getCapacitorBanks(this.localCustomer).subscribe(ires => {
            let data: any;
            data = ires.data;

            data = data.map(index => {
              this.assetID = index.id.id;
              this.aID.push({'id': this.assetID});
              return index.id.id;
            });
            console.log(this.aID);
}
}
```

#### console.log

[image: console.log]

#### dashboard

[image: dashboard]

#### complete dashboard

[image: complete dashboard]

It should show only one edit-icon per battery

Comment: What is the issue here ?

Comment: I can see in image there are 4 icons are there

Comment: Please post your Full HTML code, its diffcult to find with this code

Comment: Could you help me please?